# NetGear a600 won't connect to 5GHz

Tags: networking, drivers

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04LTS.  My wireless dongle did not work.  No surprise - it didn't work when I first got it.  I had to manually download, compile and install a driver for it.  So I tried the same thing.  This time the dongle doesn't connect to the 5GHz band on my router.  It connects to the 2.4 GHZ with no problem.  Now I've crowded my system with too many drivers and still can't get the 5GHz band.

```
 dkms status

8812au, 4.3.20, 4.4.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.4.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.4.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Why is it that the drivers I've tried will connect to the low band but not the high band?  How to I clean my system of unwanted/unused drivers?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lsusb`? Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out.  Apparently these drivers don't support hidden networks well.  I changed that setting in my router and did a clean install.  Now everything works and I learned a lot about dkms in the process.

Comment: I'm going to vote to reopen your question so you can post your own answer to help others

Answer (score 0):

So after removing all of the drivers and cleaning out dkms, I went into my router.  I had both the 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands hidden.  I left the 2.4GHz band hidden but unhid the 5GHz band.  I rebuilt the driver and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

First you have both 8812au and rtl8812au installed they will conflict since both drivers are for the wifi dongle.
Second in both cases the installed module is not the built module (possibly they are switched). It appears that rtl8812au is the ubuntu kernel module.

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` and add the line `blacklist rtl8812au`
then rebuild and reinstall 8812au. verify that the installed module matches the built module. `dkms status`

and reboot.

Comment: I gave up and did a clean install.  Got Grawp's latest driver from GitHub.        $ dkms status
8812au, 4.3.20, 4.4.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-375, 375.66, 4.4.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed                                                            Still no 5G band.  I have WinBlows 10 on a separate HDD and it pick up the 5G band with no problem.

Comment: yes,  sometimes a clean install is easiest when you get a mess. the driver is working now?

Comment: Still not working.  I've been at this for 4 days.  There was some trick I used to build a driver from the installation CD but I can't find that either.  The trick, I have the install CD

Comment: the trick is finding the right driver. do you  have secure boot on or off?? starting with kernel 4.4 in ubuntu, third party modules will not load if secure boot is on

Comment: Secure boot has never been on.  Ubuntu wouldn't load at all with Secure boot.  I built this system and everything was fine until last Friday.  There was some method I used to take the install CD (for Win 10) to build and compile a linux driver.

Comment: there is a wrapper, I don't remember the name.